# Battery in ubuntu is draining very fast (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86_64 )

Tags: battery

Some things I noticed and want to share with you before you see pictures :

- The battery reports a discharge rate of 32.8 mW
- In just 2 hrs battery decreased from 98% to 66%.
- Not doing any heavy task just sublime for normal coding stuff (3 files max open at a time)
- brave / chrome browser 4 tabs max open at a time (one youtube)

Here are some screenshots contains information related to my problem :

[System information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Odrrw.png)

[Tlp status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr5Qq.png)

[PowerTop overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heojr.png)

[Powertop device stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh4QB.png)

following things I already did to prevent this :

- installed tlp
- installed powertop

I was expecting that after installing it will start giving the battery backup it gave me before (6-7 hrs)

please help me out...

Comment: You note that you expect 6-7 hours, but in 2 hours it decreased by about one third, suggesting you _are_ getting 6 hours.

Comment: @RyanM I am sorry I forgot to mention this,  but after like 50 % it decreases way to fast making it to give around 5 hrs max. Although its not a huge difference but I am not doing any hardcore stuff.